# Какие фрукты: яблоки, бананы, абрикосы - ты бы хотел-таки съесть...?

Tags: пунктуация

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать мне, как правильно это написать? (То есть какой правильный знак препинания после второстепенных существительных, которые после двоеточия стоят?)

1. Какие фрукты: бананы, яблоки, абрикосы - ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?
2. Какие фрукты: бананы, яблоки, абрикосы; ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?
3. Какие фрукты: бананы, яблоки, абрикосы, ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?

Comment: Pumpkin 777, на этом сайте принято отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.  Скажите, пожалуйста, почему Вы игнорируете комментарии в Ваш адрес? Складывается ощущение, что Вы здесь просто развлекаетесь. Если Вы будете продолжать в том же духе, Вам перестанут отвечать.

Comment: Простите меня. Я не сразу разобрался, где эти знаки находятся. С настоящего момента буду это делать.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! Пройдитесь по своим вопросам и нажмите стрелочки и галочки на ответах (галочка может быть только на одном).

Comment: Сделано, сеньор-сэр.

Comment: Ваше предложение неверное. Вы же спрашиваете о фруктах, а сами их называете. Если давать выбор, то как-то так: *Какие фрукты бы ты выбрал? Бананы, яблоки или абрикосы?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из ваших вариантов верен первый — с тире:

***Какие фрукты: бананы, яблоки, абрикосы — ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?***

В [справочнике Розенталя (пункт 8)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) говорится:

> Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире: Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотографический аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте? (Пришв.); Везде: над головой, под ногами и рядом с тобой — живёт, грохочет, торжествуя свои победы, железо (М. Г.).

Поэтому в вашем примере двоеточие начинает перечисление однородных членов, а тире закрывает однородный ряд.

**Но!**

> Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с; Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

Это тот же 8-й пункт. Но в вашем примере постановка запятой не требуется, так что сохраняется тире.

---

И есть еще возможные варианты:

***Какие фрукты — бананы, яблоки, абрикосы — ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?***

***Какие фрукты (бананы, яблоки, абрикосы) ты бы хотел-таки бы съесть, Георг-мистер?***

В первом варианте предложение оформлено в виде **вставной конструкции с тире**, а во втором — **со скобками**.